# How to insert image into database using jbutton and display it on jlabel and jtable successfully

Tags: java, sql, swing

I created the following line of codes to enable a successful input of data into database and jtable, they are all working except for my passport(image) column, it submits the bytes into database and jtable but doesn't display the picture on jlabel unlike the other codes that also display their respective data in jtextfield, combobox e.t.c. I really need it to work using this format, though i got it working using another way(see codes below), but i prefer this way

```
private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {
            String reg1 = reg.getText();
            String name1 = name.getText();
            String address1 = address.getText();
            String parent_name1 = Parent_name.getText();
            String Phone_no1 = Phone_no.getText();
            String DateOfBirth1 = ((JTextField)DateOfBirth.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(); 
            String class1 = ClassComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String GenderCombobox11 = GenderCombobox1.getSelectedItem().toString();         
            String term1 = TermComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            byte[] passport1 = upload_path.getText().getBytes();
                    format = new ImageIcon(passport1);
                    imagLabel.setIcon(ResizeImage(format));            

            String query = "insert into JSS1_DB (reg_no, name, address, parent_name, parent_no, D_O_B, class, Gender, term, passport)"
                + "values('"+reg1+"','"+name1+"', '"+address1+"', '"+parent_name1+"', '"+Phone_no1+"', '"+DateOfBirth1+"',"
                + " '"+class1+"', '"+GenderCombobox11+"', '"+term1+"', '"+passport1+"')";        


          PreparedStatement pst;
          pst = db_connector.prepareStatement(query);         
          pst.execute();    

           Object[] objs = {reg1, name1, address1, parent_name1, Phone_no1, DateOfBirth1, class1, GenderCombobox11, term1, passport1};

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Submitted successfully");         
          pst.close();          
          JSS1_class JSS1 = new JSS1_class();        
          model = (DefaultTableModel) JSS1.JSS1_Table.getModel();
          model.addRow(objs);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kindly Input unique Student's registration no");          
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }        

    }
```

Comment: You should lookup "SQL injection" and fix your query appropriately

Comment: Could you add the `ResizeImage` class ?

Comment: Ok...It is a method @ Berger

public Icon ResizeImage(ImageIcon format) {       
        Image img = format.getImage();
        Image mypassport = img.getScaledInstance(imagLabel.getWidth(), imagLabel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon mypassport1 = new ImageIcon(mypassport);
        return mypassport1;     
    }

Comment: Honestly, unless you absolutely have to, don't. Store the image in a "known" location and then store the path to the image instead

Comment: Ok thanks @MadProgrammer